# C - Drawing rectangle using * special character based on input (For loop)

Tags: c, for-loop, console-application, drawing, nested-for-loop

I am quite new to programming and I have got an assignment which I cannot move with.

So the program must take the user input, the length and width of a rectangle and then draw the rectangle using stars `*` based on the parameters length and width. I have to do it using `for` loops, more precisely one `for` loop inside the other.
It does not work and I am stuck with it, so please if someone would be so kind to help me, I would be thankful.

Here is what I got:

```
int main() {
    
    printf("\n\n***Rectangle***");

    printf("\n\n\nInsert side a: ");
    scanf("%f", &sideA);
    printf("\n\nInsert side b: ");
    scanf("%f", &sideB);
    
    printf("\n\nRectangle: \n\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sideA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sideB; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == sideB - 1 || j == 0 || j == sideA - 1) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: What do you get instead of the desired rectangle (in which the *s have to be in the perimeter only, I suppose it because it is not clear in the question). It would be easier if you could post the whole function performing it with the relevant `main` code.

Comment: after each written character (star or space) you print a newline, how can you hope that works as expected ?

Comment: If you use `sideA` and `sideB` it would have made it easier to spot the error if you had called your loop variables `a` and `b` rather than `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- you should include `<stdio.h>`
- `sideA` and `sideB` should be defined as `int`.
- `scanf("%f", &sideA);` should be `scanf("%d", &sideA);` and the same for `sideB`. Furthermore, you should test for input failure: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions, which must be `1` in this case.
- you have a simple confusion on the coordinates: `i` should be compared to `sizeA` and `j` to `sizeB`.
- the newline should be printed outside the inner loop:

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int sideA, sideB;

    printf("\n\n***Rectangle***");

    printf("\n\n\nInsert side a: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &sideA) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("\n\nInsert side b: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &sideB) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    printf("\n\nRectangle: \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sideA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sideB; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == sideA - 1 || j == 0 || j == sideB - 1) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First step is to move `printf("\n");` down one line to outside the inner loop.

Comment: and what about to propose `putchar((...) ? ' ' : '*')` ?

Comment: @bruno: `putchar()` would be fine, but I'm afraid the ternary operator if beyond the OP's skill level

Comment: Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with this code:

1. You are printing newline for each character rather then each row.
2. You have `i` and `j` the wrong way around in your '*' test.

Move the newline to the outer loop, swap 'i' and 'j' in the `if` condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sideA; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sideB; j++) 
    {
        if (j == 0 || j == sideB - 1 || i == 0 || i == sideA - 1 ) // MODIFIED
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");  // MOVED
}
```

Alternatively be "less clever" and break it down thus:

1. Print a line of `width` asterisks (`'*'`) followed by newline.
2. Print `length - 2` lines starting `'*'`, followed by `width - 2` spaces, then '*' + newline.
3. Repeat 1.

Comment: Note this answer refers to the original question.  It does not address issues with the subsequently updated code.  I am not addressing a moving target.

Comment: Step 2 should be refined for `sideB < 2` (and Step 3 for `sideA < 2`).

Comment: @chqrlie The op refers to length and width in his text, so I used those terms, (though width and height would make more sense). I'll leave the refinement to the reader.